# How to solve this ordinary differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this ordinary differential equation?

$$
\frac{1}{m}(\log f(x))'=f(x)-1,\,\,m>0.
$$

Is this equation solvable? Is so, can anyone give me a hint?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation is soluble.  Write $y=f(x)$ and

$$\frac{d}{dx} \log{y} = \frac{y'}{y}$$

Then you can show that the equation may be rewritten as

$$\frac{y'}{y (y-1)} = m$$

Integrate both sides with respect to $x$ and solve for $y$.